# How to use two columns in a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables:

1. `Article`
2. `Subscription`

In the `Article` table I have two columns that make up the primary key: `id`, `sl`. In the `Subscription` table I have a foreign key 'idsl`.

I use this constraint :

```
constraint FK_idsl 
  foreign key (idsl) references CSS_SubscriptionGroup(id, sl)
```

But when I run the query, I getting this error:

> Number of referencing columns in foreign key differs from number of referenced columns, table X

Comment: You have a *composite* primary key, thus you need *two discrete* referencing fields in `Subscription` table

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign key referencing a 2 columns primary key in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178709/foreign-key-referencing-a-2-columns-primary-key-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Article Table I have two fields that are the primary key: id,sl. In the Subscription Table I have a foreign key 'idsl`

This design is broken - it is apparent that the composite primary key in `Article(id, sl)` has been mangled into a single compound foreign key in table `Subscription`. This isn't a good idea.

Instead, you will need to change the design of table `Subscription` to include separate columns for both `id` and `sl`, of the same type as the `Article` Table, and then create a composite foreign key consisting of both columns, referencing `Article` in the same order as the primary key, e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE Article
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    sl VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -- Other Columns

    CONSTRAINT PK_Article PRIMARY KEY(id, sl) -- composite primary key
);

CREATE TABLE Subscription
(
    -- Other columns
    id INT NOT NULL, -- Same type as Article.id
    sl VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, -- Same type as Article.sl

    CONSTRAINT FK_Subscription_Article FOREIGN KEY(id, sl) 
         REFERENCES Article(id, sl) -- Same order as Article PK
);
```

**Edit**

One thing to consider here is that by convention a column named `table.id` or `table.tableid` should be unique, and is the primary key for the table. However, since table `Article` requires an additional column `sl` in the primary key, it implies that `id` isn't unique.

Answer (score 3):

correct syntax for relation:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_OtherTable_ParentTable
FOREIGN KEY(OrderId, CompanyId) REFERENCES dbo.ParentTable(OrderId, CompanyId)
```

You must try like this:

```
constraint      FK_idsl     foreign key (id,sl)  references CSS_SubscriptionGroup(id,sl)
```