# SQL only allow foreign keys where other column matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I have two tables,

```
CREATE TABLE ActivityCodes (
    ActivityCodeID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LocationID INT NOT NULL
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE LocationSettings (
    LocationID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DefaultFooActivityCodeID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (DefaultFooActivityCodeID) REFERENCES ActivityCodes(ActivityCodeID)
);
```

with the foreign key relationship as indicated. Activity codes are valid only for the given `LocationID` and `DefaultFooActivityCodeID` in the `LocationSettings` table should be an `ActivityCodeID` where `ActivityCodes.LocationID == LocationSettings.LocationID`. How can I enforce that in SQL? Can it be done with constraints or foreign keys? Is it possible at all?

---

Edit: Just to add some clarification, this what valid data in these table should look like:

`ActivityCodes`

| ActivityCodeID | LocationID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 3 | 456 |
| 4 | 456 |

`LocationSettings`

| LocationID | DefaultFooActivityCodeID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 456 | 4 |

A location can have multiple activity codes. The default activity code for a location must be an activity code for that location. @Charlieface I tried using a composite foreign key as suggested in the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178709/foreign-key-referencing-a-2-columns-primary-key-in-sql-server) but I get an error saying `LocationID` on `ActivityCodes` is neither unique nor a primary key (I'm using MS SQL Server).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foreign key referencing a 2 columns primary key in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178709/foreign-key-referencing-a-2-columns-primary-key-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the link. Let me try to understand what that question and answer say since I'm not super familiar with SQL. Hopefully it will answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

The DDL you provide, do not means what you have describe.
The DDL describe this:
The `ActivityCodes` are independent of `LocationSettings`.
The `LocationSettings` instead depends on an `ActivityCodes` (one ActivityCodes has many `LocationSettings`)

The foreign key is well defined with this like `FOREIGN KEY (DefaultFooActivityCodeID) REFERENCES ActivityCodes(ActivityCodeID)`. If you try to insert a LocationSettings without first insert an ActivityCodes it will fail due constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key reference does not have to be a primary key.  This allows you to have two foreign key references to the same table, even if they are redundant:

```
CREATE TABLE ActivityCodes (
    ActivityCodeID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LocationID INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (LocationID, ActivityCodeID)
);

CREATE TABLE LocationSettings (
    LocationID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DefaultFooActivityCodeID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (DefaultFooActivityCodeID) REFERENCES ActivityCodes(ActivityCodeID),
    FOREIGN KEY (LocationID, DefaultFooActivityCodeID) REFERENCES ActivityCodes(LocationID, ActivityCodeID)
);
```

Although this expresses what you want, you will find that this is a bit tricky to maintain in practice.  Setting the default requires the following steps:

1. Insert a location with a `NULL` default.
2. Insert a row into `ActivityCodes` with the default activity.
3. Update the default in `LocationSettings`.