# Is it possible to have two foreign keys in an ATTRIBUTE?

Tags: mysql

Example:

## Student

```
studentId
name
```

## Staff

```
staffId
name
```

## Account

```
accountId
foreignKeyId(studentId or staffId)
username
password
usertype
```

Comment: what mysql engine are you using? and yes this does matter for me to give you an answer :)

Comment: You need either studentId or staffId as forein key ?

Comment: @Sahal, what i want to happen is that,if i will to create an account for student or for a staff, it will be saved in the FOREIGNKEYID attribute.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO strange design choice. You better go all the way around:

```
Account
-------
accountid
username
password
usertype
...

Student
-------
studentid
accountid
name
...

Staff
-----
staffid
accountid
name
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Both tables should be InnoDB.
InnoDB details - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

The following Stack Overflow answer could help.

[Multiple-column foreign key in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953035/multiple-column-foreign-key-in-mysql)