# MySQL errno 150 without solution yet

Tags: mysql, sql, database, errno

although this is a repeated question,
I have been searching through most of the similar posts, but found nothing useful.
Here's my SQL script for MySQL.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS store;
USE store;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Box (
coord VARCHAR (255),
box_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
img_path VARCHAR (256),
PRIMARY KEY (coord, box_id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tool (
serial VARCHAR (50),
tool_id INT,
descr VARCHAR (256),
box_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
tool_state BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY (tool_id),
FOREIGN KEY (box_id) REFERENCES Box(box_id)
);
```

Output is: ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 9: Can't create table 'store.Tool' (errno: 150)
Any suggestion

Comment: In your first table Box primary key consists of 2 columns but in the second one you just use 1 column

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953035/multiple-column-foreign-key-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it.It must
>   have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL
>   returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error
>   message.

I guess you have to use the same amount of foreign key, in your code you use 2 PK in table Box, so either you use only box_id as your PK or add foreign key to table Tool..

Comment: Thanks for clearing my path. PK is composed by box_id, and coord now is left as UNIQUE field. Thank you