# Add two columns from a table as a foreign key in another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have **students** table as below

[image]

I want to create a new table **certificates** using SQL query where it will have **certid** as primary key auto incremented and rollno and marks should come from students table as foreign key (correct me if I am wrong) like below:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple-column foreign key in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953035/multiple-column-foreign-key-in-mysql)

Comment: Making marks as foreign key does not make sense

Comment: Can you post your certificates table columns and data? I think all you need is a simple join on rollNo whilst you will have to keep rollNo field as FK in certificate table

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I might be wrong in terms of sql stuff but I want both the data coming together.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi check the data

Comment: @Ankit4mjis Why would `marks` be in `Students` table?  What happen if a student takes more than one course?  Which mark are you going to put in `Students` table?  It doesn't make sense to put `marks` in `Students` table.

Comment: @Eric consider that marks as full marks.
and I only want to understand that my above requirement is possible or not. Or am I missing anything?? I'm a bit learning the SQL, so please don't mind  it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create table certificates like this,

```
create table certificates (
    certId int auto_increment primary key,
    rollNo int,
    marks int,
    FOREIGN KEY (rollNo) REFERENCES students(rollNo)
);
```

Then using this command you can copy all data from students table to certificates table,

```
insert into certificates (rollNo,marks) select rollNo,marks from students;
```

Let me know if you needed this and have any issues doing it.